# Retrieve Domain Name instead of IP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, apache2

All,

I am using the following command to retrieve the domain name of my server.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

This seems to return the IP address instead of domain name like www.example.com. I looked at PHPInfo and it also lists an IP address for HTTP_HOST instead of Domain name. What do I need to change to make the domain name appear instead of IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead.

Or, you can look at every Server Variable you have available but putting this script in one of your PHP pages on this server.

```
<?PHP
foreach($_SERVER as $key_name => $key_value) {
  print $key_name . " = " . $key_value . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: That also lists IP address instead of domain name

Comment: @Vincent: If `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` lists an IP address, Apache is misconfigured, as this should contain the value of Apache's ServerName directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername

Comment: ...or just `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`  (which may not be defined if the client made a HTTP/1.0 request) contains the hostname that the client requested.

If the client requested `http://127.0.0.1/` it would contain `127.0.0.1`; for `http://localhost/` it would contain `localhost`; for `http://127.0.0.1:81/` it would contain `127.0.0.1:81`.

Comment: Is it okay to define the IP address with a host name in /etc/hosts file and probably this $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] or $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] will pick it up?

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyaddr()` can retrieve a hostname for the IP address, but only if DNS record has been set up properly

Answer (score 0):

useful link:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
use $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]